# Adding navigation controls to a slide gallery using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, pagination, gallery, slideshow

I have a slide gallery, whereby when you click on a thumbnail, it retrieves the image reference in the thumbnail and displays it in the main panel.

Now I've added navigation controls but i'm not sure how to wire it altogether so that if you click on next/previous it navigate through the thumbnail and highlight the one you are on.

The code is too long to paste here, but here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/QuXYV/

ps: JavaScript only, no jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your code and got it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QuXYV/12/).  I would recommend refactoring your code a bit to clean it up. I would say create an array of objects that hold the image url and the caption:

```
var objArray, obj;
for(var i = 0 ....) {
    obj = {
        url : "http://foobar.com/foo.png",
        caption : "Caption"
    };
    objArray.push(obj);
}
// then index with
var currObj = objArray[current];  // where 'current' is the variable you are using for state
```

Essentially what I did is move some of the code out of bindImage and into a function called 'set' (you probably want to rename this).  I also commented out the line where you remove the anchor's href.

Comment: Hi John
The link to your jsfiddle seems to be broken.

Comment: Oops. Not sure what happened there.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Commenting out the 'remove anchor href' from the top function breaks the thumbnail click function. any way to avoid that?

Comment: Try the latest link.  I did something similar to the sample code i provided.

Comment: Is there a way around this without altering the getAndDropLink function at the top? that function is used elsewhere on the site, therefore advisable not to alter it.

Comment: Alright, try that.  I simply moved it into your loop for setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you an example of slider, that you can base your solution (or maybe even change) upon.

The example (**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZenMaster/CrFRd/3/)**) is of a slider that moves `<div>` elements left and right, but you can see how the binding of the click event is done.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask followup questions.