# Add navigation to rotate through images using javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation, pagination, image-rotation

I've got a image gallery where by the user clicks on a thumbnail, it then retrieves the image and displays it in a container. Now I've added 2 buttons to navigate between images, however I'm not sure how to make the rotation work.

Can someone have a look?

http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/QuXYV/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding navigation controls to a slide gallery using JavaScript only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032554/adding-navigation-controls-to-a-slide-gallery-using-javascript-only)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my blog, I guess this is exactly what u want.
http://mycodelove.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/simple-photo-gallery-from-img-in-li/